# Javascript checkbox multipule post

Tags: javascript, checkbox

i have this form. I need the input tag email post to a standrard direction www.loc.com/standard and if checkbox checked then email input tag post also to specific direcxtion for example www.loc.com/dir1. 
Also if user select 2 checkboxes also send to both this directions including the standard one.

Thank you

Here is my code (but it doesn't work properly):

```
<form id="ms-sub-form" method="post" action="http://www.loc.com/standard">
<input type="text" name="ms-email" id="email" size="30" style="border:1px solid #ffffff; height: 30px" placeholder="Email" />

<input type="checkbox" name="operation[0]" onclick="if(this.checked){form.action = 'www.loc.com/dir1'};">CheckBox1

            <input type="checkbox" name="operation[1]" onclick="if(this.checked){form.action = 'www.loc.com/dir2'};">CheckBox2

            <input type="checkbox" name="operation[2]" onclick="if(this.checked){form.action = 'www.loc.com/dir3'};">CheckBox3
   <p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="sign">
   </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Whats te problem? When you submit the form and you get the checkbox from the form you will get the one which is checked. If both are checked you will get both

Comment: Wait didn't read the code correct. The action when click on the submit button must be pointing to your Javascript function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Comment: Are you planning to have multiple server side scripts as per the form data ?

Comment: One server with multiple mail list to sign for newsletter email.

Answer (score 0):

It should be what you need:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="operation[0]" onclick="if(this.checked){form.action = 'http://www.loc.com/dir1'};">CheckBox1

            <input type="checkbox" name="operation[1]" onclick="if(this.checked){form.action = 'http://www.loc.com/dir2'};">CheckBox2

            <input type="checkbox" name="operation[2]" onclick="if(this.checked){form.action = 'http://www.loc.com/dir3'};">CheckBox3
   <p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="sign">
   </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello KNVB,

it doesn't work also. 

If i check all the checkboxes it posts only to http://www.loc.com/dir3. Not even to standard direction.

Comment: Why you need to send to more 1 than pages?

Comment: The user is going to subscribe his email to a standard newsletter list. Also i need to give (to the user) option to subscribe to extra lists with the checkboxes.

Comment: I think you should combine 3 destination into 1.
It is because if you submit the form to 3 destination, the result is not stable.

Comment: The following script is submit to 3 server, but the result would be unpredictable:
    http://jsfiddle.net/40ynch1y/8/

Comment: Indeed... the result is unpredictable. The code still posting only to one list and not even to standard.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to work properly.

Thank you all for your help.